# Imwarp fails on sequential rigid trasformations, due to isRigid funcion

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I'm performing a sequential rigid transformation of some frames of a video.
The code looks like this:

```
lastReg = imregtform(video(:,:,i), video(:,:,i), 'rigid', optimizer, metric);

for i = 2:finalFrame
  i
  % Save moving and fixed images into matrices (needs later)
  Imob = video(:,:,i);
  Ifix = video(:,:,1);

  % Get affine transformation object
  lastReg = imregtform(Imob, Ifix, 'rigid',...
  optimizer,metric,'InitialTransformation',lastReg);

  % Register
  videoReg(:,:,i) = imwarp(Imob,lastReg,'OutputView',imref2d(size(Ifix)));
end
```

As you can see, the code recursively uses the last registration parameters stored in "lastReg", which is the last rigid registration employed for the previous frame pair.

Everything works fine, but suddenly I get this error

```
Error using imregtform>validateInitialTransformation (line 502)
The isRigid method of the InitialTransformation must return true when
TransformationType is 'rigid'.
```

In fact, if I type "isRigid(lastReg)" I get a zero.

The strange thing is that it happens kind of "randomly" into the for loop! More precisely:

1) The code works fine for some loops of the for cycle, than suddenly doesnt

2) Each video sequence gives the error at a different iteration of the
    for loop, which is different for each video.

What do you think could be the problem, and how to fix it??

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the value of i in the very first line; video(:,:,i)...?

Comment: It is the one coming from a previous for loop. I could have writtine 1 instead of i, it wouldn't make a difference. 
I just wanted to have a empty rigid transformation object to start the loop, otherwise it was necessary to add an "if" before the "% Get affine transformation object", to check if "lastReg" exsists or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer to your problem.  I was having a similar problem with a translation transformation type.  I did some debugging in the imregtform code, and found out that the affine2d object it was returning ***sometimes*** had very small numbers (like 5.4e-9) instead of zeros in certain parts of its T matrix.  isTranslation and isRigid checks the tform.T matrix to make sure certain parts are exactly zero.  For example:

```
A.T = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; X Y 1];
B.T = [1 0 0; 5.4e-9 1 0; X Y 1];

isTranslation(A) = true
isTranslation(B) = false
```

As a workaround I had to post-process the tform object output by imregtform to zero out any of those random small numbers.  I could then seed the next call of imregtform with the post-processed tform from the previous call.

I just submitted a bug report to MathWorks on it s well, so hopefully they can fix it for future versions.

So that was the problem for my 'translation' transformation type use of imregtform... I suspect your problem with 'rigid' is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is caused by lastReg not being an affine2D object. That's just a guess though, so
what if you type this:

```
 % Get affine transformation object
     lastReg = imregtform(Imob, Ifix, 'rigid',...
     optimizer,metric,'InitialTransformation',lastReg);

 lastReg = affine2d(lastReg.T); % transform the tform vector into an actual affine2d object.


% Register
  videoReg(:,:,i) = imwarp(Imob,lastReg,'OutputView',imref2d(size(Ifix)));
```

Comment: It is an affine2d object (otherwise we have found a bug in the imregtform object I guess :D).
I checked in the workspace and it is a 1x1 affine2d.

Anyway I'm going to try now, it takes a while for my laptop to register the frames so I will update you asap :)

Comment: Ok I see you're right that was just a guess as I said :)

Comment: what if you give an index to lastReg? So that as the 'InitialTransformation' parameter, you would use lastReg(i-1) for example?

Comment: Like creating a cell array so to keep all the previous values of lastReg? I could (and since I'm disperate I will :P ), but I'm not really convinced.. Isn't the value returned by the function "imregtform" going to automatically delete the last content of "lastReg" and then repopulate it with the new value?

I don't see why this should help, that's all :D

Comment: yeah well other than that I fail to see why your code would not work; I use pretty much the same code with translation transformations and it works fine. Good luck! If you find the solution please update your post :)